# Javascript image sliding

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

After my previous post on controlling a singular HTML element using JQuery, I thought I'd be okay but I've yet to be caught in a somewhat confusing position again.

I was able to get the function working without passing individual elements, however I do not want every animation on my page to trigger on one image rollover.

I shall provide a JSFiddle link below along with my script.

```
        <!-- slide image -->
    <script>

        function slideImage(elem)   

        {

            //Hide both the hover and overlay divs
            ".galleryHover".hide();             

            ".galleryOverlay".hide();


            //When the container div is hovered over trigger these events...
            $(".galleryContain",$(elem).parent()).hover(function()
            {
                //Slide .galleryHover along z-axis from -400 to 0 so its visible at a speed of 0.6s
                $(".galleryHover",$(elem).parent()).stop().show().css({ "left" : "-400px"}).animate({ left : 0}, 600);

                //Fade in the background overlay in 0.75s to 0.9 opacity
                $(".galleryOverlay",$(elem).parent()).stop().fadeTo(750, 0.9)

                //On mouse out...
            }, function(){

                //Slide .galleryHover +450 on the z-axis to provide illusion of sliding off the other way.
                $(".galleryHover",$(elem).parent()).stop().animate({ left : 450}, 750)

                //Over the course of 1 second, fade the background to 0 opacity.
                $(".galleryOverlay",$(elem).parent()).stop().fadeTo(1000,0)

            });

        });

    </script>
```

I am trying to trigger this event when my DIV is hovered over (This is where I believe I am going wrong, as I am certain you can trigger the event in this way)

```
                <!-- OBJECT TO CONTAIN 1 GALLERY ITEM -->
                <div onhover="slideImage(this);" class="galleryContain">

                    <div class="galleryOverlay">

                    </div>

                    <div class="galleryHover">

                        <h1>Cool hovering slide effect!</h1>

                         <a href="#" onhover="slideDiv(this);"> <p class="blueText">08/03/2013 - ESPN Spoof for HP :</p> </a>

                    </div>  

                </div>      <!-- END FIRST ITEM -->
```

JSFiddle can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/w3RqG/2

Please note that this version works as it targets and animates **ALL** elements on a mouseover

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Regards

Alex.

Comment: You're declaring global variables outside of the scope of hover - i'll post an example in just a moment but essentially change all the content and overlay to $(this).find('.galleryHover') and $(this).find('galleryHover')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scope variables to the hover so you're targeting the correct Hover & Overlay elements. In your example you're assigning `content` to all '.galleryHover'. By moving it inside the hover function and specifying `.find()`, you search for only that one within the element.

[Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w3RqG/4/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $('.galleryOverlay, .galleryHover').hide()
    $(".galleryContain").hover(function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $content = $this.find('.galleryHover'),
            $overlay = $this.find('.galleryOverlay');

        $content.stop().show().css({ "left" : "-400px" }).animate({ left : 0}, 600);
        $overlay.stop().fadeTo(750, 0.9) 
        } ,function(){
        var $this = $(this),
            $content = $this.find('.galleryHover'),
            $overlay = $this.find('.galleryOverlay');

            $content.stop().animate({left : 450}, 750)
            $overlay.stop().fadeTo(1000, 0)
        });
});
```

(Sorry for wiping your comments)